# Why is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ anti-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $f:V^d\to W$ be a d-linear map with $V$ and $W$ being $\mathbb{K}$ vector spaces. We say that $f$ is anti-symmetric if $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_d)=0$ whenever $x_1,x_2,...,x_d\in V$ are not pairwise distinct.

Why is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ anti-symmetric, where $$f(x,y)=xy.$$

So if $x=y$ then $f(x,x)=x^2$ but why should this be equal to $0$, I don't understand. Any insight into this will be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What makes you think $f(x,y)=xy$ is anti-symmetric?

Comment: Quite the opposite, that function is *symmetric.*

Comment: Your example is *not* the same as example 7.7.  If the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$, you are not working with real numbers - there are no $\mathbb{R}$s involved!

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: What question are you trying to answer?  Did you make up the example yourself or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: I am trying to understand Example 7.7

Comment: The definition you give is the definition of alternating, not antisymmetric; they are equivalent over every field except fields of characteristic $2$, which is the point of Example 7.7. This example has nothing to do with the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:I didn't see the edit and answered just for the case where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$.

Your function **isn't** anti-symmetric. In fact the only 2 anti-symmetric function of $\mathbb{R^2}$ would be $f(u,v)=c*det(u,v)$.

As far as I have seen , anti-symetric means that $f(u_1,...,a,b,..u_d)=-f(u_1,...,b,a,..u_d)$ and that is why it is called that way.

Notice that this implies your definitions and it, is in fact equivalent. Because,**wlog**, $f(a,a,..,u_d)=-f(a,a,...,u_d)\Rightarrow f(a,a...,u_d)=0$. On the other hand, if we have your definiton then

$f(u_1,...,a+b,a+b..u_d)=0 \Rightarrow$

$f(u_1,...,a,a...,u_d)+f(u_1,...,b,a,..u_d)+f(u_1,...,a,b,...,u_d)+f(u_1,...,b,b,...u_d)=0 \Rightarrow$

$f(u_1,...,a,b,..u_d)=-f(u_1,...,b,a,..u_d).$